# Android: Google Map Custom Marker resets after map Loads

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am adding custom markers to Google map iterating over an arrayList I am able to see my custom marker icon once but instantly it resets to one other one all markers chaneg to same icon

here is code snipplet

```
 for (int j = 0; j < mUsersList.size(); j++) {
            int index = j + 1;
            Bitmap bmp;
            if (newIds.contains(mUsersList.get(j).Whistleid)) {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            } else {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.marker);
            }

            Bitmap mutableBitmap = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setTextSize(15);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
            canvas.drawText("" + index, mutableBitmap.getWidth() / 3, mutableBitmap.getHeight() / 2, paint);
            Marker marker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(
                            new LatLng(mUsersList.get(j).coordinates.getDouble(1), mUsersList.get(j).coordinates
                                    .getDouble(0))).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mutableBitmap))
                    .anchor(0.5f, 1).title(mUsersList.get(j).category + " : " + mUsersList.get(j).provider));

        }
```

Some points that may give a clue

**1) All the  markers are at almost same location average distance may be around less than 5 meters**

**2) All markers take icon as whichever is given in else part bmp value  please refer code snipplet above**

Comment: Animate camera on Last Marker...

Comment: @MD thanks for your response , what is actually happening why is cion being reset

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the markers are really really close to each other with respect to what the map is configured to scale. You can increase the sizeScale attribute and center your map to the location where most of your markers are... (If this does not effect your map display data). Because if within such a small area in which markers are placed and the area displaced on the webpage has a huge difference it would look like all markers are reset to just one point.